# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when i run 'phantomjs' command in ubundu12.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, segmentation-fault, phantomjs, coredump

when i tried to install phantomjs, after all progress ,i run

```
$:phantomjs -v . 
$ : Permission denied
```

then i run

```
$: sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/share/phantomjs
```

There after whenever i run the command "phantomjs" ,
 ubuntu throws the error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Hi.., i got resolved by self . i had delete all phantomjs related file from **/usr/** folders . -

Comment: then i want to thanks @Klas Lindbäck for formatting my question .

Comment: You should write your solution as an answer and accept it. That way the question will be removed from the list of unanswered questions, and it will be easier for others with the same problem to find your solution.

Comment: i had added my answer bellow what i followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by older versions of phantomjs that were installed in other places.
I removed the phanthomjs related file from the following locations, and then it worked:

```
/usr/bin/phanthomjs
/usr/local/share/phanthomjs
/usr/local/bin/phanthomjs
```

Comment: but i can't install latest version of phantomjs .